# UIImagePickerController presentViewController - Status bar issue in ios7

Tags: iphone, ios7, uiimagepickercontroller, statusbar

I'm facing status bar issue in iOS 7.
[image]

Below is the code for presenting this image picker

```
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary]) {

        picker.sourceType =UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

        if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(presentViewController:animated:completion:)]){
            [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:^{

                if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7)
                    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES
                                                            withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
            }];
        }
        else {
            [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
        }
    }
```

and when I'm trying to pick image the screen is like below

[image]

Can any one help me to solve this issue?

Comment: are you using assetlibrary for it ?

Comment: no, i'm not using that

Comment: @Dev, just added the complete solution for you. check the edit part of my answer please.

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)aPicker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

// for iOS7
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate)]) {

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
}
```

Edit:

here is a much easier solution.

add the boolean View controller-based status bar appearance in your plist and set its value to NO. then in your app delegate `application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` declare the following:

```
[application setStatusBarHidden:NO];
[application setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleDefault];
```

that should take care of the status bar when you start the camera. then for the camera roll part just add the following method in the view controller that you have placed the codes for the `UIImagePickerController`

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
}
```

that should take care of the modal view status bar when you select the camera roll.

hope this helps out man.

Comment: setStatusBarHidden:YES doesn't hide the status bar if you click outside the image picker, to remove it.

Comment: in your info plist add this boolean View controller-based status bar appearance and set it to no. then plug in [application setStatusBarHidden:NO];
    [application setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleDefault]; in your app delegate application did finish lunching method. that will hid the status bar when camera is fired.

Comment: My scenario is like this, in my iPad application.
1. I have UIImagePicker in a popover controller.
2. I have set boolean for View controller-based status bar appearance as NO, in plist.
3. also in didFinishLoading '[application setStatusBarHidden:NO]'
4. All is good till now, no status bar in any view controller.
5. But when I show image picker inside popover controller the status bar appears.
  5.1. If I select any image, the status bar ... it disappears. This is bearable.
  5.2 But if I tap outside the popover, popover disappears but not status bar.
so point issue is at point 5.2 Any advice.

Comment: apply the view controller code snippet in that view controller which has the pop up modal code within it. then when you select a picture and return to that view the status bar will not be there. if you still have a problem build a mock project with your code and upload it somewhere so i can take a look at it for you.